# Adding a syntax style text to a plot in Python using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm wanting to incorporate a text box with code style highlight in a plot in matplotlib, and I'm wondering whether there's a method to do so? Thank you in advance for your consideration and suggestions.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/gallery/recipes/placing_text_boxes.html) ?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Not exactly. I want to add a "python code as a text" rather than the LaTeX code it has as a text str.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I can try like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#create data
x = [3, 6, 8, 12, 14]
y = [4, 9, 14, 12, 9]

#create scatterplot
plt.scatter(x, y)

font = {'family': 'serif',
        'color':  'red',
        'weight': 'bold',
        'size': 10
        }

box = {'facecolor': 'none',
       'edgecolor': 'green',
       'boxstyle': 'round'
      }

#add text with custom font

code = """
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

"""
#add text with custom font
plt.text(6, 9.5, code, fontdict=font, bbox=box)
```

Output look like:

[image: output]

Reference: https://www.statology.org/matplotlib-add-text/

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for the solution where the red text become the code style and syntax highlighter style.